# Android API23 permission still denied after run-time permission request

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm extracting a bitmap in my app right now. It requires a READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Since I'm working with Android 6 (API23), I have 
 1. declared such permission in Android.manifest as

```
<uses-permission tools:node="replace" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission tools:node="replace" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. checked permissions during runtime( using
   *ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)* 
   in MainActivity and then another
   *onRequestPermissionsResult(..)* 
   callback to handle the stuff after I get such permission).

However I still fail to fetch the bitmap I want, with an error indicating that I have insufficient permissions.

I also checked the phone's app settings regarding my app's permission and switched on and off the "storage" option, a dialog did popped up requesting permission, but still, after allowing access for the app I get the same error:

**07-12 14:54:59.255 31895 31911 E DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uricontent://media/external/images/media from pid=18177, uid=10077 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()**

In *MainActivity*

```
String[] perms = {"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
int permsRequestCode = 200;
```

In *OnCreate*

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, perms, permsRequestCode);
```

The *callback* in *MainActivity*:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(permsRequestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch(permsRequestCode){

            case 200:
                Log.e(TAG, "checking permissions");
                if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&&isPreview){
                    bitmap.getPixels(left, 0,0,0,0,w/2,h);
                    bitmap.getPixels(right, 0,0,w/2,0,w/2,h);
                    Log.e(TAG, "left and right stored");
                };
                //writeAccepted = grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Am I still missing anything here?

Comment: You should avoid putting a `android:maxSdkVersion="23"` attribute btw.

Comment: I've changed it accordingly~

Comment: I gave a brief answer related to your problem, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38411306/3819836